# Need help adding max and min value to counter

Tags: javascript, function, counter

I am trying to make a counter which starts at 0 and ends at 12 What I have right now is a counter that I can't cap. So basically, I am having trouble setting a max and min. Here is my code:

```
<div class="counter8">
  <label id="blank"></label>
  <div class="operations">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dec_num8()" class="dec opr8">⇦</a>
    <span class="count8">0</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="inc_num8()" class="inc opr8">⇨</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var add=document.querySelector(".inc");
var sub=document.querySelector(".dec");
let counter8=document.querySelector(".count8");



function inc_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;
  counter8.innerText=temp8+1;
  if (temp8 > 12) {
    counter8.value = 12;
  } else {
    counter8.value = temp8;
  }
}
function dec_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;
  counter8.innerText=temp8-1;
}
</script>
```

The increase button was one of my attempt at making this work but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to cap the values.

```html
<div class="counter8">
  <label id="blank"></label>
  <div class="operations">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dec_num8()" class="dec opr8">⇦</a>
    <span class="count8">0</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="inc_num8()" class="inc opr8">⇨</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var add=document.querySelector(".inc");
var sub=document.querySelector(".dec");
let counter8=document.querySelector(".count8");



function inc_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;
  counter8.innerText=Math.min(12,temp8+1);
}
function dec_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;
  counter8.innerText=Math.max(0,temp8-1);
}
</script>
```

If you wanted to fix your code using if branching you could do:

```
if (temp8 >= 12) {
  temp8 = 12;
} else {
  temp8++;
}
counter8.innerText=temp8;
```

Or on one line: `temp8 = temp8 >= 12 ? temp8 : temp8+1`
For the minimum one just the flipped version

Comment: I tried something similar, but still suck with syntax. Thank you so much for your help. Much Appreciated. Will Accept this as answer when it lets me in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really limit min counter on your minus button. And also you only increment it after you check for condition.
So for you examples:

```
function inc_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;

  if (temp8 >= 12) { // here changed to >=
    counter8.innerText = 12; //also use innerText, not value
  } else {
    counter8.innerText=temp8+1;
  }
}
function dec_num8(){
  var temp8=parseInt(counter8.innerText) >> 0;
  if(temp8 <= 0){ //here changed to <=
  counter8.innerText = 0;
  }else{
  counter8.innerText=temp8-1;
  }
}
```